# How to correct my regex to not match particular expressions starting with a character

Tags: php, regex

In PHP I am trying to create a regex without success, which should match expressions consisting of numbers and a single 'end'character, only of the numbers are not preceeded by an `F`. Here is an exmaple string to match

```
$test = "123A456C789XF765S333333AF444G";
```

and the following regex

```
preg_match_all("/(?<!F)(\d+)([ASTCGX])+/", $test, $matches)
```

**finds** the following  expressions:

```
123A
456C
789X
65S
33333A
44G
```

while I **expect** only the following matches:

```
123A
456C
789X
333333A
```

I do not want to have the numbers `\d+` split up to match the regex. An expression like `F\d+[ACXSG]+` should **not** be matched! How to achieve this?

Comment: I don't see `678X` in `$test`, also why don't you expect `444G` ?

Comment: Your regex is correct as far as I'm concerned...?

Comment: Good catch HamZa,, I fixed the text. I do not expect `444G` because it is preceded by an `F`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use this:

```
preg_match_all("/(?<![\dF])(\d++)([ASTCGX])/", $test, $matches);
```

explanation:

```
(?<![\dF])       # not preceded by F or a digit (numbers can't be trunked)
\d++             # one or more digit (with a possessive quantifier, optional but better)
[ASTCGX]         # one of these characters
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault, `333333A` is of course expected. And maybe I even understand your suggestion, and it seem to work. Thanka a lot!

Comment: @casimir-et-hippolyte Just curious, is the `++` needed?  What would happen if it was left as just a single `+`?

Answer (score 0):

just use \d{3,0} instead of \d++

```
preg_match_all("/(?<!F)(\d{3,})([ASTCGX])+/", $test, $matches);
```

Comment: Why this restriction on three digits or more?

Comment: cause that's what he want based on results he want to achieve... PS. seriously - a minus? when result is exactly what he ask for?

Comment: No, it doesn't do what he's asking for. Take the string `"12A"`. Why shouldn't it be matched?

Comment: if @Alex would like to have for e.g. 65S he would put that in expected results

Comment: He doesn't want `65S` because it's only two digits long, but because that number is actually `765S`, and he wants to it only if it isn't preceded by `F`.

Comment: yes I get it - I forgot about "example" in "Here is an exmaple string to match"

Comment: The length of the number can vary between 1-6 digits.